# When piping sed command, output becomes all spaces

Tags: linux, bash, sed, pipe

This is for a lab I have in a class, the professor has told me to use sed to remove all punctuation and double spacing by piping together several sed commands. When I pipe the commands together my output is a file full of empty characters. the command chain he lays out:

```
sed '<expr1a>' usdeclar.txt | sed '<expr1b>' | sed '<expr1c>' | sed '<expr1d>' | sed <expr1e>' | sed '<expr1f>' | sed '<expr1g>' | sed '<expr1h>' > sed_edits.txt
```

My command chain:

```
sed 's/./ /g' usdeclar.txt | sed 's/,/ /g' | sed 's/./ /g' | sed 's/:/ /g' | sed 's/;/ /g' | sed 's/-/ /g' | sed 's/  / /g' | sed 's/""/ /g' >sed_edits.txt

cat sed_edits.txt
output: 165 lines of blank spaces.
```

what is wrong with my command chain? If I run the sed commands separately the output is fine, but the professor specifically wants me to run the commands like this, any time I add more than one sed command the output is 165 lines of blank spaces. I'm still new to everything so I'm sure it's a simple mistake I'm making. Thanks to anyone who takes the time to read this!

Comment: [Regular expression to match a dot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989661/10765659).

Comment: Realized I forgot to escape the special characters working as desired now!